# I got "Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.String', 'double'" on the 4th from bottom line. Any fixes? Thanks

Tags: java

Below is code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab_04_01_SalesTax
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What was the price of your purchase?");

        String price = myObj.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Price is: $" + price + " before tax.");

        int totalPrice = price * .05;
        System.out.println("Total price is: $" + totalPrice);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `price` is a String and Java doesn't know how to calculate for example `"A" * 0.05`. Maybe you meant `double price = myObj.nextDouble();`? BTW `myObj` is a very bad name for any object.

Comment: Don't know if you can see this comment but what is a good name for an object? Thanks.

Comment: @Yamos It's a `Scanner`.  So, names like `scanner`, `input`, `in`, `keyboard`  might be good.

Comment: https://www.brainstobytes.com/writing-good-variable-names/ is a good lecture about good variable names. Basically, if you read the code in six month, do you know what meaning `myObj` has? In such a simple code using `scanner` is good enough (or any of the names that OldDogProgrammer mentioned)

Comment: boom. Finally figured it out. First-week learning java, it feels good to get it right. Thanks to everybody who helped.

Comment: So, since you figured it out, and there were no answers, consider deleting the question.